# How to name an anonymous Object in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, class, object

I have part of my code which creates several instances of a Player class by the following code:

```
player.push(new Player(i, positions[randomPosPlayer]));
```

Hence I'm not using the conventional way i.e. `var somePlayer = new Player(x,y);`
Assuming 3 players are created, all of them appear as anonymous Objects. How can I name them while maintaining the key-value of each Object?

Comment: If you're not referencing the objects later, what are you trying to accomplish with that? Any variable referencing an object is only referencing a certain place in memory, and that place in memory will exist regardless of whether there's a standalone variable referencing it or not (assuming it doesn't get GC'd)

Comment: They will be placed on a multidimensional array and will be referenced later in order for each player to move on the array-board and in sake of a cleaner code and I'd like to have the name of the Players appear.

Comment: It sounds like you should just pass the desired name for the player to the constructor..? That way you can (for example) just access the `.name` property whenever it's needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you are using custructor functions or the es6 class syntax but either way you can "name" your players in it's constructor by something like this:

```
let allPlayers = {};
function Player(x,y,name){
   if(name)allPlayers[name] = this;
   //...other constructor stuff
}
```

and just pass the name when you create it:

```
player.push(new Player(i, positions[randomPosPlayer],"CustomName"));
```

and then you can simply get the players by name using

```
let p = allPlayers["CustomName"];
```

or even by accessing the attribute directly if you are sure a player with this name exists:

```
let p = allPlayers.CustomName;
```